# Markdown for codes on webpage

Tags: html, css, markdown

I am experienced with CSS and a beginner in Python. In the past, while writing blogs/webpages with codes, I would simply just create a div with a particular class and make it a code bloc with different colour and font-family, etc.

However, these days I've seen so many beautiful applications of markdown such as [github-markdown-css](https://sindresorhus.com/github-markdown-css/) or [dillinger](http://dillinger.io/). But I really don't know where to start learning. For instance, I am not even sure where to execute the installation instruction below...

```
$ npm install --global generate-github-markdown-css
```

If I really want to really go beyond linking html files/blog posts with CSS and do some nice-looking markups, what are the steps necessary? 
To make it more solvable as a question in this forum: if I just have a html file and want to create a code bloc showed above by typing

```
> line 1
> line 2
```

instead of

```
<div class="codebloc">
    line 1<br/>
    line2
</div>
```

Where should I start?

Comment: if you are interested in using markdown, this is a great resource (https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For instance, I am not even sure where to execute the installation instruction below...
>
> `npm install --global generate-github-markdown-css`

This command, which you can execute in your terminal, will install the specified npm package `generate-github-markdown` globally, making it available from anywhere on your system. To execute it you'll need npm installed on your computer. If you're not already familiar with npm, I suggest reading [the official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm) or  [this guide on Sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/). Since it installs the package globally, you can execute the command from pretty much anywhere on your computer.

> How do I make code blocks in Markdown?

Markdown will automatically convert text with for spaces in front to code, which looks like this:

```
console.log("This code is cool");
```

If the Markdown parser supports GitHub Flavoured Markdown, which most parsers do, you can also wrap your code with three back-ticks ```. If you want `inline code` you can use just a single back-tick ` on both side of the code.

If you want to learn more about how to do various things with Markdown, including some more examples on how to write code blocks, I recommend looking at [this page](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet).

Comment: thanks, i will start from `npm `'s documentation then!